# Task boolean Java

Tags: java

Имеются блоки для вычисления переменных `Boolean`. Каждый этап вычисления сложный и его нельзя выразить 1 строчкой и желательно пропускать вычисления, если возможно.
Предложите алгоритм для минимизации количества вычислений при расчете x и y, используя возможности языка.

```
class A {
    private boolean x,y;

    public void calculate(){
        boolean a,b,c,d;
        {a = }
        {b = }
        {c = }
        {d = }
        x = a && b && c;
        y = b && c && d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можете обернуть вычисление каждой из переменных `a`, `b`, `c` и `d` в соответствующие методы (`getA()`, `getB()`, ...), затем переписать код вот так:

```
boolean bandc = getB() && getC();
boolean x = bandc && getA();
boolean y = bandc && getD();
```